# Why do HTML tables interfere with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm trying to create an email ticket template that features a small table where clients can quickly see the subject and description of their ticket. Thus far, everything looks fine...
[image: good]
...until the table is added, completely destroying the formatting on the right side of the boxes!
[image]
What is causing this? I have tried removing parts of the table's CSS in case a certain property was destroying everything, but it seems to be the table itself. Is there a way to bypass this? An alternative?

The snippets below may show as oddly-formatted, but appear perfect in emails. I am unsure of how to explain this either, but take my word for this.

Intact snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   html {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
   }
   .box {
    width: 75%;
    border: 20px solid #bbbcbc;
    margin: 0;
   }
   .case-number {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #535659;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   .date-opened {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #bbbcbc;
    color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   .body {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   .ttable th {
    width: 20;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #bbbcbc;
    border: 1px solid #bbbcbc;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
   }
   .ttable td {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #bbbcbc;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="box">
   <div class="case-number">case number</div>
   <div class="date-opened">date opened</div>
   <div class="body">
    this is where the body of the ticket will be.
    <div class="ttable">
     table here
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Snippet that breaks:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   html {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
   }
   .box {
    width: 75%;
    border: 20px solid #bbbcbc;
    margin: 0;
   }
   .case-number {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #535659;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   .date-opened {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #bbbcbc;
    color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   .body {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   .ttable th {
    width: 20;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #bbbcbc;
    border: 1px solid #bbbcbc;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
   }
   .ttable td {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #bbbcbc;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="box">
   <div class="case-number">case number</div>
   <div class="date-opened">date opened</div>
   <div class="body">
    this is where the body of the ticket will be.
    <div class="ttable">
     <table>
      <tr>
       <th>Subject</th>
       <td>TICKET SUBJECT HERE</td>
      </tr><tr>
       <th>Description</th>
       <td>TICKET DESCRIPTION HERE</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [This might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115197/embed-html-table-in-email)

Comment: Well, `.ttable td` is going to take precedence over `.body`

Comment: @RobertHarvey why?

Comment: Because that's how CSS works.  You specified `class="body"` in a div, but then in a descendant div you specified `class="ttable"`.  Any CSS settings in  `class="ttable"` will override corresponding settings in `class="body"`.

Comment: Strip all of your table css values and create your email without them. As you have it looking the way you wanted without formatting, add in the formatting individually. Oh and maybe pay attention to my answer in your last question.

Comment: CSS uses [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for determining how styles are inherited to descendants. `.body` is a class selector, and has a score of 10; `.ttable td` has a class selector (10), followed by a type selector (1), for a total score of 11.

Comment: Outlooks dont like div's ... just wanted to put it out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS elements not displaying properly in emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404319/css-elements-not-displaying-properly-in-emails)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to send this template using email. you need to write you style as in-line in table..Otherwise classes will not give the expected result.

you can also refer below article ::

```
https://emailmonks.com/blog/email-coding/step-step-guide-create-html-email/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   html {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
   }
   .box {
    width: 75%;
    border: 20px solid #bbbcbc;
    margin: 0;
   }
   .case-number {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #535659;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   .date-opened {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #bbbcbc;
    color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   .body {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   .ttable th {
    width: 20;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #bbbcbc;
    border: 1px solid #bbbcbc;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
   }
   .ttable td {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #bbbcbc;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="box">
   <div class="case-number">case number</div>
   <div class="date-opened">date opened</div>
   <div class="body">
    this is where the body of the ticket will be.
    <div class="ttable">
     table here
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width:100%` from `.body` and then `.ttable th` width is missing a %.

Also to raise an earlier comment. Outlook doesn't play well with div elements. You might want to build this module entirely using tables OR add in conditional Outlook only tables